# Access 2007 can VBA code be fired following direct data upload to tables?

Tags: ms-access, vba

When a user enters data into a form control, the On Update event fires code which enters data to the table via other controls on the form. So for example, entering a BMI of 31 into one field updates the corresponding Obesity field to show that the person is clinically obese.

When I upload data directly into the table, is there a way for me to get this VBA code to run and update all the necessary values, without having to manually go into each record via the form and do something to fire it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in version 2007, Access 2010 includes "data macro's" which can monitor table updates. For 2007 you would need a copy running on a standalone machine somewhere that could check the table in a loop and then fire events if it detects a change.

Comment: I'd be the only one loading the data, and that will happen before the database gets passed to users. Would the way to go be to write a function to loop through each record in the table, check the value of this field and update the associated field if there is a value there?

Comment: @Chelle To be honest, I would try to avoid updating fields in a table based on data, e.g. in this case the BMI, it would be better to have some logic on your forms which could read this BIM value and then calculate the forms fields without them having to be physically stored in a table